# SourceTree install behaving strangely

Tags: git, sourcetree

Hi we are in the process of transitioning to Git/SourceTree/Bitbucket and are a bit new to this. I installed Source Tree on a colleagues machine and few funny things happen which I don't remember happening on mine.

1. SourceTree didn't have a version of Git installed - so it gave us an embedded option which we installed but I was a bit confused by
2. There wasn't a default global git ignore we had to create one
3. We couldn't stash we had to explicitly set the username and email in the terminal before it would work and even then it didn't seem to stash properly

I suspect I've done something wrong/different during the install and I was wondering whether anyone could shed any light on this? Perhaps during the setup process with Altassian/activating a licence? Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't provide a clear description of the issue and it is not useful for the readers.

Comment: I agree, I though I was describing some  kind of obvious issue but it wasn't. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this isn't really an issue, I reinstalled it and it started working. I've probably inadvertently done something without realizing it.